# print mysql rows only once

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following data in my database table 'resbook'

```
      htno             name             fname

       2              Rakesh             Rahul
       2              Rakesh             Rahul
       2              Rakesh             Rahul
       2              Rakesh             Rahul
       2              Rakesh             Rahul
       3              Himesh            Krishna
       3              Himesh            Krishna
       3              Himesh            Krishna
       3              Himesh            Krishna
       3              Himesh            Krishna
```

I Have a form asking users to enter 'htno' and iwant to display the 'name' & 'fname' for the respective 'htno' only once as the same rows are repeated five times

here is my code

```
<?PHP
$userInputEntities = htmlentities($userInput);
echo $userInputEntities;

$username = "admin";
$password = "123456";
$database = "resbook";
$server = "localhost";
$db = new PDO ("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", "$username", "$password");

if ($db) {
$id = $_GET['id'];
$NAME = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM resbook WHERE htno=:id");
$NAME -> execute(array(':id'=>$id));
while ($row1 = $NAME->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo "<td align=left><font size='2'> STUDENT NAME :</font><font color='blue' size='2'><b> " . $row1['name']. "</b></font></td>";
echo "<strong>&emsp;&emsp;||&emsp;&emsp;</strong>";
echo "<td align=left><font size='2'> FATHER NAME :</font><font color='blue' size='2'><b> " . $row1['fname']. "</b><p></font></td>";
}
```

Using this code i am getting the Output repeated 5 times as 5 rows are there for each htno in table

```
STUDENT NAME : Rakesh            ||        FATHER NAME : Rahul
STUDENT NAME : Rakesh            ||        FATHER NAME : Rahul
STUDENT NAME : Rakesh            ||        FATHER NAME : Rahul
STUDENT NAME : Rakesh            ||        FATHER NAME : Rahul
STUDENT NAME : Rakesh            ||        FATHER NAME : Rahul
```

I want the output only once like this

```
STUDENT NAME : Rakesh            ||        FATHER NAME : Rahul
```

Please do help me

Comment: You need to use `distinct` in your query !

Comment: Why do you store every value multiple times to begin with?

Comment: no adding distinct is nt wrking

Comment: Are you sure that many rows are exactly same ?

Comment: It may not be `DISTINCT *`, better would be `DISTINCT (htno),fname,name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct(htno),name,fname FROM resbook WHERE htno=:id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` in query

```
$NAME = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT(htno),* FROM resbook WHERE htno=:id");
```

Comment: no its not working :( @yogesh Suthar

Comment: @Aryan Not working means it showing all records rather than single record

Comment: @Aryan Try edited query.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$NAME = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM resbook WHERE htno=:id");
```

to

`$NAME = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM resbook WHERE htno=:id");`

DISTINCT keyword is used to return only distinct (different) values.

EDIT:-

You may also try this:-

```
SELECT htno,distinct(name),fname FROM resbook WHERE htno=:id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try LIMIT 1:

```
SELECT * FROM resbook WHERE htno=:id LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This will always return only one record.

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT *` doesn't cut it. You should run `DISTINCT` only only the specific field you want returned unique.

Try

```
SELECT distinct(htno),name,fname FROM resbook WHERE htno=:id
```

Answer (score 0):

write quyery in this way.... SELECT * FROM resbook WHERE htno=id LIMIT 1

Hope it will help you.